# how to find out a cell that has checkbox in it in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a table with several columns and rows, in some cells there are checkboxes.
so how can i flash those cells in watir?
Is there method that returns what element is located in particular cell?

Comment: Without the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce the issue, it's just guesswork.  I suggest posting the HTML and any watir code that you've written to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing sample HTML, this is a total shot-in-the-dark, but here's a possible approach.

Given this contrived HTML snippet:

```
<table>
  <tr><td id="foo"><input type="checkbox" name="foo"></tr></td>
  <tr><td id="bar"><input type="checkbox" name="bar"></tr></td>
  <tr><td id="text">text</tr></td>
</table>
```

You could use the `checkboxes` method to locate the checkboxes and then use the `parent` method to get the id of the cell that contains the checkbox (assuming the cell has an id):

```
b.checkboxes.each { |checkbox| puts checkbox.parent.id}
#=> foo
#=> bar
```

If you want to `flash` the checkboxes, this might work depending on how the page is implemented:

```
b.checkboxes.each { |checkbox| checkbox.flash}
```

Like I said, total guess.  But it's the giving season, so there you go.